# boost::bind: from a called function, cannot change object's state

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
class foo {
   public:
        int bar;
        void _quux(boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
           std::cout << "quux:" << ++bar << std::endl;
        }
        boost::system::error_code connect(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
        {
            std::cout << "bar:" << bar << std::endl;
            if(!bar) {
                _socket.async_connect(endpoint, 
                    boost::bind(&foo::_quux, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
                return boost::asio::error::would_block;
            }
        }
        tcp::socket _socket;
}
```

Why `bar` stays 0 within `connect()`, even if it get's changed to 1 in `_quux` (it's always 0->1, so state is lost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem (except for the strange use of an hardcoded error_code)

Watch here:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class foo {
   public:
        int bar;
        void _quux(boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
           std::cout << "quux:" << ++bar << std::endl;
        }
        boost::system::error_code connect(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
        {
            std::cout << "bar:" << bar << std::endl;

            if(!bar) {
                _socket.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&foo::_quux, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
                return boost::asio::error::would_block;
            }

            return {};
        }
        tcp::socket _socket;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    foo f { 0, tcp::socket { svc } };

    tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), 6767);
    f.connect(ep);

    svc.run();
}
```

Prints:

```
bar:0
quux:1
```

If you **erronously** expect the value to change withing `foo`, then that is clearly a wrong expectation: `_async` indicates *asycnronous* execution. In essence, the value will be updated **when updated**, not any time earlier.

Comment: in my case, every additional call to _quux() has bar: 0. Is it something caused by binder? I see it creates copy of object's when doing `bind()`, but I've already attempted to pass pointer to foo* to _quux, no effect. io_service is running.

Comment: @kagali-san so, indeed, you were expecting the wrong thing. Fix: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7571720/